# ternary code from Hadamard matrix

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking for a direct proof of this statement:

"A $12\times 12$ Hadamard matrix is the generator matrix of a ternary selfdual (linear) $[12,6,6]$ code $C$."

That the length is 12 is clear. As the rows of a Hadamard matrix are orthogonal, the code $C$ is self-orthogonal ($C\subseteq C^\bot$). The code has minimum weight at most 6 also follows directly (if the first row of the Hadamard matrix is made into all 1's, subtracting the second row which has equally many 1's as -1's yields a code word of weight 6).

However, if fail to see (1) that a Hadamard 12x12-matrix has rank 6, or that that $C^\bot\subseteq C$ and (2) why the minimum weight cannot be smaller than 6.

The reason why I ask for a 'direct' proof is that I suspect these codes might have to do something with the ternary Golay code which I want to avoid using...

Comment: Because it is self-orthogonal the rank of the matrix (viewed over $GF(3)$) obviously cannot be higher than six. I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to find six linearly independent rows. Also, because $(\pm1)^2\equiv1\pmod3$ and because any word $x$ is orthogonal to itself, its weight has to be a multiple of three. Thus it suffices to exclude the possibility of a weight three word. Shouldn't be too hard?

Comment: I agree. Once you have that $C^\bot\subseteq C$, a codeword of weight 3 would give 3 columns of a Hadamard matrix adding to the zero vector, which is impossible.

Comment: Yes.  I'm afraid this *is* the (extended) ternary Golay code.